# How to fix my C Circular List Double Free Error

Tags: c, circular-list

I am having trouble fixing the memory leak associated with my code for a circular list. Any help would be appreciated! I could use help identifying how to fix the memory leak in question. It is related of course to double freeing my code which is the issue. Yet, i provide a null pointer check that is being completely ignored by my code, is there anything i can do here to fix this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char value;
    struct node* next;
};

void insertion(struct node** list);
void removal(struct node** list);

int main() {
    char userInput;
    struct node* list = NULL;
    printf("Enter \"i\" to insert a new element, \"r\" to remove an element, \"q\" to quit: ");

    while (scanf(" %c", &userInput) == 1) { 
        if (userInput == 'q') {
            break;
        }
        else if (userInput == 'i') {
            printf("Enter character to be enqueued (inserted): ");
            insertion(&list);
        }
        else if (userInput == 'r') {
          removal(&list);
        }

        printf("Enter \"i\" to insert a new element, \"r\" to remove an element, \"q\" to quit: ");
    }
  
    return 0;
}

void insertion(struct node** list) {
    char userInput;
    struct node* newNode;
    newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    scanf(" %c", &userInput);
    
    if (*list == NULL) {
        newNode->value = userInput;
        newNode->next = newNode;
        *list = newNode;
    } 
    else {
        newNode->value = userInput;
        newNode->next = (*list)->next;
        (*list)->next = newNode;
        *list = newNode;
    }
}

void removal(struct node** list)
{

    struct node* temp;
    if (*list == NULL || strlen(*list) == NULL)
        printf("List is empty.\n");
       
    else if(*list != NULL){
        temp = (*list)->next;  
        (*list)->next = temp->next;
        printf("%c", *list);
        if ((*list)->next == NULL) {
            *list = NULL;
            return;
        }
        printf("The character removed was an \"%c\" \n", temp->value);
        free(temp);
    }
}

a.out
Enter "i" to insert a new element, "r" to remove an element, "q" to quit: i
Enter character to be enqueued (inserted): a
Enter "i" to insert a new element, "r" to remove an element, "q" to quit: r
The character removed was an "a"
Enter "i" to insert a new element, "r" to remove an element, "q" to quit: r
List is empty.
Enter "i" to insert a new element, "r" to remove an element, "q" to quit: i
Enter character to be enqueued (inserted): a
Enter "i" to insert a new element, "r" to remove an element, "q" to quit: i
Enter character to be enqueued (inserted): b
Enter "i" to insert a new element, "r" to remove an element, "q" to quit: i
Enter character to be enqueued (inserted): c
Enter "i" to insert a new element, "r" to remove an element, "q" to quit: r
PThe character removed was an "a"
Enter "i" to insert a new element, "r" to remove an element, "q" to quit: r
PThe character removed was an "b"
Enter "i" to insert a new element, "r" to remove an element, "q" to quit: r
PThe character removed was an "c"
Enter "i" to insert a new element, "r" to remove an element, "q" to quit: r
PThe character removed was an " "
*** Error in `a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001fb1050 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x9a749)[0x7ff38e49c749]
a.out[0x4008fa]
a.out[0x400771]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7ff38e43bd45]
a.out[0x400649]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:2d 313533460                          /home/students/connelg2/Code315/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 00:2d 313533460                          /home/students/connelg2/Code315/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 00:2d 313533460                          /home/students/connelg2/Code315/a.out
01fb1000-01fd2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ff288000000-7ff288021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff288021000-7ff28c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff28e39d000-7ff28e3b2000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 8855075                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7ff28e3b2000-7ff28e5b1000 ---p 00015000 fc:00 8855075                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7ff28e5b1000-7ff28e5b2000 r--p 00014000 fc:00 8855075                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7ff28e5b2000-7ff28e5b3000 rw-p 00015000 fc:00 8855075                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7ff28e5b3000-7ff28e5b4000 r-xp 00216000 fc:00 8855075                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7ff28e5b4000-7ff28e5d7000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 9172916                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7ff28e7be000-7ff28e7c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff28e7d2000-7ff28e7d6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff28e7d6000-7ff28e7d7000 r--p 00022000 fc:00 9172916                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7ff28e7d7000-7ff28e7d8000 rw-p 00023000 fc:00 9172916                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7ff28e7d8000-7ff28e7d9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff38e1fd000-7ff38e200000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 8429031                    /usr/lib64/libksplice_helper.so
7ff38e200000-7ff38e3ff000 ---p 00003000 fc:00 8429031                    /usr/lib64/libksplice_helper.so
7ff38e3ff000-7ff38e400000 r--p 00002000 fc:00 8429031                    /usr/lib64/libksplice_helper.so
7ff38e400000-7ff38e401000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff38e401000-7ff38e402000 r-xp 00204000 fc:00 8429031                    /usr/lib64/libksplice_helper.so
7ff38e402000-7ff38e5c7000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 9019623                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7ff38e5c7000-7ff38e7c7000 ---p 001c5000 fc:00 9019623                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7ff38e7c7000-7ff38e7cc000 r--p 001c5000 fc:00 9019623                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7ff38e7cc000-7ff38e7ce000 rw-p 001ca000 fc:00 9019623                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7ff38e7ce000-7ff38e7d3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff38e7d3000-7ff38e7d4000 r-xp 003d1000 fc:00 9019623                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7ffd2ac61000-7ffd2ac82000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd2ad4a000-7ffd2ad4d000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd2ad4d000-7ffd2ad4f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

Comment: Before looking at your code, any circularly linked list is not going to have any null values if it has items (unless it has a sentinel.) Are you sure you don't override the value with non-null? Usually you remember a node and test if the `next` value is that node.

Comment: I initialize the struct list to null of course then override those values as I enter them. The problem I have then is checking when I free these values are they null. I could do that with a regular LinkedList, is it different here, and are such checks not possible?

Comment: If you draw out an example, you will see that none of the `next` are ever null in a circular linked list; so instead of ending when null, you have to end when the first pointer is the current pointer the second time around.

Comment: Right. So instead of checking NULL I'd check if *list == (*list) ->next it'll check for that. Though that wouldn't let me access the last element of my list. Where if I entered a and b. I'd be able to remove a but not be able to remove b.

Answer (score 1):

A null circular list is a special case. In `insertion`, you've accounted for the boundary null to not-null. However, in `removal`, when moving from not-null to null. (Since a well-formed circularly-linked list that is not null, none of it's `next` are null, so removing redundant code.)

```
if(*list != NULL) {
    temp = (*list)->next;  
    (*list)->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

If the list size is one, then `temp == *list`. You `free(temp)` and now you are pointing to an invalid memory location since `temp == *list`. One solution is to check if `temp == temp->next` (size one,) and if so, set `*list = NULL` (size zero.)